# TemplateDoesNotExist at /en/user/login/ when tried to visit the login url in Django 2.2

Tags: python, django, upgrade

I am upgrading a Django application from 1.11 to to 2.2. I have completed all the migrations and everything but I am facing this error constantly `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: registration/login.html`. I am still currently learning Django apologies in advance if I am missing something stupidly simple.
I have attached the error message picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITqNg.png) and the files that might be relevant to this error message.
Just for clarification in my `settings.py` I have the following under TEMPLATES:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
                "django.template.context_processors.tz",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Here are the othert files that might help debugging:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from userApp import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as django_contrib_auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.rate_limit_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^rate_limited/$', views.rate_limited, name='rate_limited'),
    url(r'^logout/$', django_contrib_auth_views.LogoutView, {'template_name': 'userApp/logged_out.html', 'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^password_change/$', django_contrib_auth_views.PasswordChangeView, {'template_name': 'userApp/password_change_form.html', 'post_change_redirect': reverse_lazy('userApp:password_change_done')}, name='password_change'),
    url(r'^password_change/done/$', django_contrib_auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView, {'template_name': 'userApp/password_change_done.html'}, name='password_change_done'),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', django_contrib_auth_views.PasswordResetView, {'template_name': 'userApp/password_reset_form.html', 'email_template_name': 'userApp/password_reset_email.html', 'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('userApp:password_reset_done')}, name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', django_contrib_auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView, {'template_name': 'userApp/password_reset_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', django_contrib_auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView, { 'template_name': 'userApp/password_reset_confirm.html', 'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('userApp:password_reset_complete')}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', django_contrib_auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView, {'template_name': 'userApp/password_reset_complete.html'}, name='password_reset_complete'),
```

**views.py**

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from ratelimit.decorators import ratelimit
from django.forms.utils import ErrorList

from .forms import MyUserCreationForm, UserProfileForm
from .utils import ReCaptcha

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@ratelimit(key='post:username', rate='10/5m')
@ratelimit(key='post:password', rate='10/5m')
@xframe_options_exempt
def rate_limit_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(request.GET.get('next', reverse('mapApp:index')))

    if request.limited:
        return redirect(reverse('userApp:rate_limited'))
    print('Hits')
    return LoginView.as_view()(request, template_name='userApp/login.html')

def rate_limited(request):
    return render(request, 'userApp/rate_limited.html')
```

I have tried following the fixes on this on stackoverflow since this seems a very widespread problem for a lot of people but the solutions didnt work for me. For some reason, the login.html file is not found. I can see that existing but not sure why its not being found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `template_name` to the *constructor* of the login view, so:

```
return LoginView.as_view(template_name='userApp/login.html')(request)
```

Comment: Hey @Willem Van Onsem, that worked like a charm! Thank you!